# Model fields from json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, backbone.js

I have model user

```
window.User = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        "id": null,
        "login":  "",
        "password":  "",
        "role":  ""
      }
});

window.UserCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: User
});
```

json response:

```
{
  "id":1,
  "login":"log1",
  "password":"psw1",
  "role":
    {
      "id":1,
      "name":"user"
    }
},
```

I have json response with all roles:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"user"},{"id":2,"name":"admin"}]
```

How create dropdown form with all roles and after set it to model user when i create a new user

Comment: Are you asking how do you bind a `<select>` to a collection using backbone?

Comment: Yes, i want a create drop down form with role.name ("user","admin") from json, my problem when i set it to user, i have role = null .

Comment: How are you getting the json response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a drop down at render time and select the correct option, you could define a template and then using when the view is rendered.

Template:

```
<script type="text/html" id="rolesSelectTemplate">
    <select id="selectRole" name="userRole">
        <% _(allRoles).each(function(aRole) { %>
        <% if (aRole.get('IsSelected') == "selected") { %>
        <option value="<%= aRole.get('id') %>" id="<%- aRole.get('id') %>" selected="selected"><%- aRole.get('name') %></option>
        <% } %>
        <% else { %>
        <option value="<%- aRole.get('id') %>" id="<%- aRole.get('id') %>"><%- aRole.get('name') %></option>
        <% } %>
        <% }); %>
    </select>
</script>
```

Function:

```
render: function(){
  // do something first

  // Assuming you are able to init the users and roles collection with JSON

  var selectedRole = this.model.get('role');

  allRoles.each(function (aRole) {
     aRole.set('IsSelected', "");
     if (selectedRole && selectedRole.id == aRole.get('id') /* if the nested role attribute is a simple object or else use selectedRole.get('id')*/) {
        aRole.set('IsSelected', "selected");
     }
  });

  var allRolesDropDown = _.template($("#rolesSelectTemplate").html())({
      allRoles: allRoles.models,
  });

  $("#allRolesDropDownElement").append(allRolesDropDown);

  // do something else
  return this;
}
```